# Network printer doesn't accept job from Debian Linux, no errors in error_log

Tags: linux, printing, debian, cups

There is a shared printer at my workplace. We send jobs and then go to the printer and authenticate, so printer prints your documents only when you present at it. Periodically, we change domain passwords, so I also have to change it in /etc/cups/printers.conf (windows users just change domain password). So, that's how it works.
But, suddenly, it stop receive my jobs. When I send job I have no errors and have this:

```
sudo tail /var/log/cups/access_log
localhost - - [14/Apr/2015:12:15:14 +0300] "POST /printers/Generic-PCL-6-PCL-XL HTTP/1.1" 200 499 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [14/Apr/2015:12:15:14 +0300] "POST /printers/Generic-PCL-6-PCL-XL HTTP/1.1" 200 1273674 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [14/Apr/2015:12:17:59 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 183 Renew-Subscription successful-ok
```

On cups page in browser it shows state for job - "Pending since (date/time)".
It seems like job was sent successfully, but when I came to printer I've got nothing and no job in my queue. Our IT support fix problems only for Windows users and who on Linux - on their own. So, I don't know what to do and what logs I should inspect. Please, help.

Comment: Did You update Your Debian recently?

Comment: Yes, I update it every two weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, some updates broke it down. But I have found another solution - I add printer not via samba, but via lp and it doesn't ask username/password:

```
cat /etc/cups/printers.conf
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.5.3
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter KonicaMinolta>
UUID urn:uuid:0f60c08a-ecfb-326a-421c-86aa3519147b
Info MyCompany Office printer
Location WestCorridor
MakeModel Generic PostScript Printer Foomatic/Postscript (recommended)
DeviceURI lpd://Company_printer_server_address/lp
State Idle
StateTime 1429265417
Type 8433692
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

If somebody can provide another solution or some explanation why it is so, I will be glad to see.

Answer (score 0):

As far as debugging you can view more data in your CUPS logs if you edit your /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file, find the section "loglevel" change "info" to "debug"

Then you should restart CUPS with:
`/etc/init.d/cups restart`

Then your log will be in 
 /var/log/cups/error_log